# Stubbing a method on instance of a class with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm new to testing with sinon and trying to get the hang of stubbing. I'm trying to test a function that receives a request object, grabs some properties off it, and passes it to an instance of a class that makes a get request to an external service.

Ex:

```
exports.getMyThings = (req) => {
  const reqOpts = {
    qs: req.query
  };

  return apiInstance.get(req.route, reqOpts);
};
```

The `apiInstance` is instantiated in the file where I'm exporting my `getMyThings` function.

I'm trying to stub out the `apiInstance.get` method so I can test that my `getMyThings` function is working correctly and passing it the right arguments.

I've tried to write the stub by importing the class into my test file, and then creating a stub instance:

```
const MyClass = require('.../blahblah)
const apiInstance = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass);
```

and

```
const apiInstance = new MyClass();
apiInstance.get = sinon.stub();
```

but inside my `getMyThings` function the `apiInstance.get` method isn't the wrapped one - it's the original. The wrapped instance only exists inside my test. This makes sense, but I'm not sure how to get around it. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I didn't find a solution but the workaround I went with is just to export the `apiInstance` and import it into my test file. This works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
const returnMe = () => 'sinon rocks!';
sinon.stub(apiInstance, 'get').callsFake(returnMe);


result = apiInstance.get();
// Do asssertion for result to equal to the returnMe();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const MyClass = require("./api");
const apiInstance = new MyClass();

exports.getMyThings = (req) => {
  const reqOpts = {
    qs: req.query,
  };

  return apiInstance.get(req.route, reqOpts);
};
```

`api.js`:

```js
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype.get = async function get(route, reqOpts) {
  return "real data";
};

module.exports = MyClass;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { getMyThings } = require("./");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const MyClass = require("./api");

describe("50726074", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should pass", async () => {
    const getStub = sinon.stub(MyClass.prototype, "get").resolves("fake data");
    const mReq = { route: "/api/thing", query: { id: "1" } };
    const actual = await getMyThings(mReq);
    expect(actual).to.be.equal("fake data");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(getStub, "/api/thing", { qs: { id: "1" } });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  50726074
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (37ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    95.24 |      100 |    83.33 |    95.24 |                   |
 api.js        |    66.67 |      100 |       50 |    66.67 |                 3 |
 index.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/50726074